# NodeJS + Route with custom ACL

Tags: node.js, express

i am newbie in nodeJS. i have an issue with route.

**SiteRoutes.js**

```
module.exports = (app, express) => {
    const router = express.Router();
    const Globals = require("../../configs/Globals");
    const SiteController = require("../controllers/SiteController") ;
    router.post('/changeStateSite', Globals.isAdminAuthorised, (req, res, next) => {
        const siteObj = new SiteController().boot(req, res);
        return siteObj.statusSite();
    });
    app.use(config.baseApiUrl, router);
}
```

**Globle.js**

```
static async isAdminAuthorised(req, res, next) {
  // checking the role. currently only admin  role consider so we have set a static role as a admin.
}
```

right now `Globals.isAdminAuthorised` is used for the ACL, but i need to pass the custom user role in that function like `Globals.isAdminAuthorised(['admin','customer'])` so how can i do that?

As when i pass the same its throw the error as below:

[image]

please help me on the same.

Comment: Check This: https://github.com/rahulshukla-rs/node-express-mongodb-folder-structure-with-auth

Answer (score 0):

you can make that middleware a function that returns the handler function with  `(req, res, next)` signature, so basically it will take that array as a parameter.

```
// e.g roles is that array that you can pass to do authorization logic based on that
static async isAdminAuthorised(roles) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
    // check if the roles are included in that array for example or whatever...
  }
}
```

then you can just execute that function inside your router there like how you wrote up there

```
router.post('/changeStateSite', Globals.isAdminAuthorised(['admin', 'customer']), (req, res, next) => {...}
```